# App deployed on heroku but not opening.Have used python

Tags: python, flask, heroku

this is the error i am getting.

this is the 3 time i am getting same error while deployment.
I also checked the logs. The log file contents are:

please help

```
2021-03-23T19:58:37.705318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/%20deployed%20to%20Heroku" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=c3e2c6e3-0762-46f5-b2fd-99149f594594 fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T19:58:38.517056+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=dea037a8-d4ee-429f-a31a-595d79c430cb fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T19:58:45.302966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=f4584f03-44f1-4117-aabb-6d7e6d888a2e fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T19:58:46.898144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=fc38ae35-5afb-4a41-a8fb-a96574232c7d fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T19:59:18.687973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=9f7e3d6f-7356-4994-b8d4-0f9b1656b679 fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T19:59:19.522940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=926260ee-1f96-4ed6-90f0-e62bc10e7f13 fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T19:59:55.796315+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=9e4a1ad9-c826-430a-837d-6c3bb1623629 fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T19:59:56.428470+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=36e2296a-8364-42a3-b647-65136ea59972 fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T20:01:35.260787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=e0070481-0492-4b10-975b-27ddbb086646 fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T20:01:36.411104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=0a59ff26-3a8d-45d4-a3b6-030f8126fc8b fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T20:04:08.260298+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=e9e66103-fd75-4f88-9a8b-728379b146a4 fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-23T20:04:09.542606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=co2-emission-pre-diction.herokuapp.com request_id=88e2ee70-4247-4afa-9d9f-ebce57af9533 fwd="157.45.119.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Re deploy your github repo and check view the live build logs. It should give a better understanding of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have `Procfile` in your top-level directory.

Heroku uses the `Postgres` database, and for that it requires these packages to be installed:

- gunicorn
- psycopg2

You can do that by running:

```py
(venv)$ pip3 install psycopg2 gunicorn
```

Remember to update your `requirements.txt` file to include these two packages because Heroku will build your application using the dependencies in the file.

Update `Procfile` as follows:

```py
web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn <your-entry-to-the-app-file>:app

# You can remove flask db upgrade if you don't need it
# Entry file is set in FLASK_APP variable
```

Set your `FLASK_APP` variable

```py
(venv)$ heroku config:set FLASK_APP=app.py
```

Commit your changes, and a remote Heroku repository and push to Heroku

```py
(venv)$ git commit -m 'Add changes for Heroku deployment'
(venv)$ heroku git:remote -a <name-of-your-heroku-app>
(venv)$ git push heroku master

# Output
Enumerating objects: 1170, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1170/1170), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (391/391), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1170/1170), 691.88 KiB | 43.24 MiB/s, done.
Total 1170 (delta 760), reused 1148 (delta 750)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
# ...
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 59.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v18
remote:        https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/your-app-name.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man !! It worked perfectly..  :-)